# Unable to create a new team in TFS

Tags: tfs

I am the TFS administrator for a particular team project collection on our TFS2013 server.

When trying to create a new team via the web interface, I get the following error:

```
Access Denied: Doug McDonald needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit project-level information
```

This is really odd, as I have full permissions in every aspect of the server. What's even stranger is that if I try to add the team for a second time it says:

```
Group [Test] already exists
```

Which implies it's already created part of the 'team' (oddly it says group, but I imagine part of the team creation involves adding a group (and possibly an area)).

This is not a problem on any other existing project, or if I create a new project. Other admin level users in our organisation also get the same error on a different machine.

Has anyone seen this kind of thing before or got any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: Is this server an upgrade from a previous version?

Comment: @MrHinsh Yes it is, it was 2012 and has been upgraded to 2013, with various other update x's applied, I think we've on update 3 or 4 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the owner of the Team Project (anyone in the Project Administrator group) has messed with the permissions.

Just because you have collection Admin does not guarantee project admin. This is by design as there may be sensitive data in a project that should not be accessible outside of the teams.

I would look at the effective permissions that your account has. Click the Cog (top right) and in the admin system go to the security tab.

Note: Denied always overrides allow. Never use deny unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Yeah my thoughts exactly but this is not the case, everything is effective allow.

Any ideas as to any specific odd (non visible) situations which could cause this kind of thing?

Comment: Have you tried sticking your account directly into the Project Admin group?

Comment: So, I got the bottom of it. Turns out I was checking my permissions through the groups I was a member of (Project Admins, <Team Name> Team, and 'Software Developers') All of which had 'allow'.

What I didn't check, was my own 'user' level permissions, as I'd assumed that none would have been set. Seems at some point in the past, in an effort to lock down aspects of the TFS instance 'Domain Users' had 'deny' set. I had to remove this to allow the team permissions to sign through.